# I'am confused that the random quick sort is slower than normal quick sort

Tags: java, algorithm

With the Introduction to algorithm .The Professor intro that the random quick sort can decrease the  percentage of bad situation and improve the performance of time cost.But I wonder if there any problem with my code that cause the result 
in contrast.
Here are my java code

```
public class quickSort {
    public final int size = 200000;
    public final int times = 10;

    @Test
    public void quick_sort() {
        int test1[] = new int[size];
        int test2[];
        int k = 0;

        long t1 = 0;
        long t2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            test1[i] = i;
        }
        test2 = test1.clone();
        while (k < times) {

            shuffle(test1);
            shuffle(test2);
             long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
             split1(test1, 0, test1.length -1);
             t1 += System.currentTimeMillis() - start1;

            long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            split2(test2, 0, test2.length -1);
            t2 += System.currentTimeMillis() - start2;
            k++;
        }

        System.out.println("normal quick sort time is" + t1 + "ms");
        System.out.println("random quick sort time is " + t2 + "ms");
    }

    public void split1(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (start >= end) {
            return;
        } else {
            int middle = sort(arr, start, end);
            split1(arr, start, middle - 1);
            split1(arr, middle + 1, end);
        }
    }

    public void split2(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (start >= end) {
            return;
        } else {
            int middle = random_sort(arr, start, end);
            split2(arr, start, middle - 1);
            split2(arr, middle + 1, end);
        }
    }

    // random quick sort
    public int random_sort(int[] arr, int start, int end) {

        int random = start + new Random().nextInt(end - start + 1);
        int key = arr[random];
        int loop = start;
        int front = random == start ? start + 1 : start;

        while (loop <= end) {
            if (loop == random) {
                loop++;
                continue;
            }
            if (arr[loop] < key) {
                int temp = arr[loop];
                arr[loop] = arr[front];
                arr[front] = temp;
                front = front + 1 == random ? front += 2 : front + 1;
            }
            loop++;
        }
        if (front < end) {

            int temp = arr[random];
            arr[random] = arr[front];
            arr[front] = temp;
        } else {
            front = end;
        }

        return front;
    }

    // normal quick sort
    public int sort(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        int loop = start;

        int key = arr[start];
        int front = start + 1;
        while (loop <= end) {

            if (key > arr[loop]) {
                int temp = arr[loop];
                arr[loop] = arr[front];
                arr[front++] = temp;
            }

            loop++;
        }
        if (front != 1) {
            int temp = arr[front - 1];
            arr[front - 1] = arr[start];
            arr[start] = temp;
        }
        return front - 1;
    }

    // shuffle the Array
    public void shuffle(int[] arr) {
        int length = arr.length;
        int random_num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             random_num = new Random().nextInt(length);
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[random_num];
            arr[random_num] = temp;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: What happens if you don't shuffle `test1`?

Comment: @ClarkKent stack overflow....Why?But if i decrease the length of the Array ,The random quick sort is really quick than the normal sort!! It's really three times performance!But how does the stack overflow if does't excute the shuffle???

Comment: I haven't done quicksort in years, but IIRC, quicksort's worst case is `O(n^2)` because of what it chooses for its pivot in the event that the data is sorted in either forward or reverse order. When you randomize the pivot location or shuffle the array before running quicksort, it becomes an amortized `O(n lg n)`.

Comment: @ClarkKent I am know that.But why does the jvm stackoverflow without shuffle Array?There is a new question appear... Only the wrose situation the random quick win...I confused than before....;

Comment: Because the data is already sorted, I'm guessing that in your sort, the value of `middle` is incrementing sequentially, causing up to 200,000 frames of activation to be added to the stack.

Comment: @ClarkKent yeah,Stack overflow because the to many frame,but Once shuffle , the problem dismiss! It's to strange!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112917/discussion-between-clark-kent-and-jason-long).